# Why was our site's 13-year-old, very first question closed by a moderator 4 days ago as "needs details or clarity" without a clear explanation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, moderation

Web Applications Stack Exchange's very first question "[How do I delete my Facebook account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1/7584)" was posted more than 13 years ago:

> I don't trust Facebook's new privacy settings and have decided to delete my account, but I can't find the kill switch.
>
> Does anyone know how I can delete my Facebook account?
> <sub>– 
> Ivo Flipse,  Jun 30, 2010</sub>

This question has been viewed 52,000 times, has a positive score of 162 (+164/-2), and has three answers with double-digit scores, including the accepted and highest-voted one with 89.

For 13 years, it has been open, and the traffic and continued voting activity on this question and the answers indicate it has been clear and is important to the community. Over that time, the question was never once flagged for closure by any community member or mod ([question's timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/1/timeline)).

To my surprise and disappointment, four days ago a moderator closed this post as "needs details or clarity." No additional explanation was provided. I don’t see how the reason provided applies, and I don’t think this question deserves to be closed. It is as clear and straightforward as it was 13 years ago. I’m curious what prompted the moderator to think that it suddenly "needed details or clarity".

The "needs details or clarity" close reason should be for questions that are ambiguous, vague, or unclear about what the actual question is, but the issue stated in the question is clear and understandable. I do not see what further details or clarity are required.

Also, if it is likely that a closure is controversial or unclear, mods should include their reasons with enough detail for others to understand.

**Can the moderator please explain why they closed this important question?** Was there a recent change in the site policy or community consensus that affected this question? Is it related to the [closure of dozens of other questions for apparently not showing research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584)? Or does it [not meet certain quality standards](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5008/7584), like some of those closed questions?

Comment: Related meta discussion post: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that it is OK as it stands so I have reopened it.

I've had a chance to discuss this with the other moderators, and there are ongoing discussions about the level of research that we expect users to do before posting questions here. Nothing has been decided yet, and I think that closing questions like this is pre-empting these discussions in assuming a level of research that may not be what we finally agree on.

That said, it is an old question and perhaps should have some sort of notice attached. However, the closest note I can add is "Content Dispute", which doesn't really cover this situation.

Comment: Thank you for reopening it.