# Why was this question asking how to view all the messages one posted in a Slack channel closed by 1 mod?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

The question [How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117076/18147)  was closed. It was posted over two years and a half ago, attracted 12,000 views, 24 upvotes and not a single downvote. Why was the question closed by 1 mod?

The mod left a few comments but no clear reason:

1. At first the reason was "Nowadays questions having the same body as the title aren't allowed", which is ridiculous since the question is more than two year old. Also, as far as I know, this isn't a reason to close the question on https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com
2. Then I believe I was told that showing research effort is a requirement on webapps, which also confused me as, to the best of my knowledge, this isn't a reason to close the question on https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com. See  [What are the sites that allow questions without details and research?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357580/178179): there is no rule  across all SE sites stating that research must be shown.

Could someone please clearly give a reason for the closure? Is it because "Nowadays questions having the same body as the title aren't allowed" (I don't see it written clearly anywhere), is it because "showing research effort is a requirement on webapps" (if so, the vast majority of questions should be closed), or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Questions, no matter how old or new they are, no matter if they have been answered or not, no matter if they have comments or not, they should be reviewed according the current guidelines.

The question quality rules doesn't allow to post questions having the same body and title. This is the case of the referred question and the reason to be closed.

[image]

---

The title of the question should describe briefly but precisely what is being asked. The body of the question should include the question details and any research. The spirit of this is that askers do and share their effort to find the answer by themselves. This have being explained in so many different ways.

By the other hand in the case of Slack, as it happens with a lot of "software as a service", it has multiple apps for different platforms, web, Windows, Mac, Android, iOS. In someway the question body should make it clear that the question is about using or direclty interacting with the web app as on this site only questions about using web app are on-topic.

It's worthy to note thats Slack has publicly available help resources and there are lot of user created content so there is no excuse to have a question body without including any detail or research.

---

From [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357586/289691) to [Title and question body are the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193632/289691)

> The [current Ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) doesn't allow to post a new question having the same body as the title. It also limits the title length to be between 15 and 150 characters while the body minimal length is 30 characters.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: ok fixed https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117076/18147 can you reopen?

Comment: At this moment the fix doesn't really look to me that improved the question, maybe I'm tired, I will review it again later when I have rested.

Comment: My two cents on this: the question currently has 29 upvotes (36 for the answer), so it's clearly useful (at least it helped me find one of my messages from the last days which I wasn't sure anymore where I posted). Also, if all it takes to clearly state the question is the phrase "how can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?", why complicate it further? Ok, having the same text for the title and the body looks strange, but that's fixed now (even if the clarification in the body is not really needed), so... ?