# Why did I receive a suspension for some action I had done and discussed with a mod over 1 year before the suspension?

Tags: discussion, moderators, account-suspension

I received a 30-day suspension. I was confused by the reason, so I [asked](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5003/18147) on Meta and [was told](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5010/18147) by a mod that the reason was:

> You should refrain from reposting questions that have been deleted for being low quality or having no answers.

The last time I did such a repost before the suspension was over 1 year before the suspension. At that time, I believed it was ok to repost a 0-score question deleted by Roomba, and I stopped doing such reposts after a mod here told me they had a different interpretation of what the rule should be.

Anyway, why did I receive a suspension for some action I had done and discussed with a mod over 1 year before the suspension? That makes no sense to me.