# Why is this question on how to view all the messages one posted in a Slack channel kept closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, moderation

I don't understand why [How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117076/18147) is kept closed. I posted a [meta question about it](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4788/18147) a few years ago, and the given reason, from my understanding, was lack of research. Since a CM recently stated that [showing research is not required](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147), I flagged the question for reopening, but the flag was [declined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MnSE.png) with no explanation. Why is the question kept closed?

---

I'll answer below to some feedback that [D.W.](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17465/d-w) gave.

> - The body of the post must explicitly articulate a question.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a question.  This post does not ask any question in the body of the post.  A question normally ends with a "?".

This is not a rule. If you read [Should "Title Says It All" questions be edited or closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119410/178179) that you linked to, there is no consensus on such a rule. The second most upvoted answer clearly state "**there are many questions which really don't need anything beyond the title to explain what's desired in the question.**"

Your question [After upgrading to iOS6, all my apps are gone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/71006/20338)
 is a good example: the question is simply "After upgrading to iOS6, all my apps are gone. Did they move to a new place? How do I get them back?" and there is no need to add any details.

Also I note that my question received 33 upvotes and only 4 downvotes, which demonstrates an overwhelming positive feedback from SE users.

This following comment on my [meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4788/18147) also received 4 upvotes:

[image]

> - People have already given extensive feedback on the question, but no one has has taken steps to address that feedback, at least not yet.  The [prior feedback](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4788/17465) includes "questions having the same body as the title aren't allowed", etc.  You were given a link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257762/160917 and ["Title-only" questions (i.e. questions without body) should be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66119/160917), which has more detail.  As that post said at the time, "This [has been] explained in so many different ways".  Everyone who is interested in that question has had an opportunity to edit the post to address this, but no one has taken the opportunity to do so.

I did incorporate the feedback. See the question edits. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/117076/revisions What else should I add in the question?

> The fact that the question was posted several years ago is not sufficient reason to re-open the question; to re-open a question, it must meet current-day standards.

True, and IMHO The question does meet current-day standard, as evidenced by all the meta links I provided (showing research is not compulsory + many questions which really don't need anything beyond the title to explain what's desired in the question.)

> Re-opening can be done by the community.  It does not require diamond-moderator action or flags.  Diamond-moderators are not necessarily obligated to take action on flags requesting re-opening; they are free to leave it up to the community to vote as it chooses.

Closed questions on WebApps are [almost never](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5180/18147) reopened by regular users only: "[Only 1 question got reopened in all of 2023 without moderator help](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1794029/post-closed-reopened-without-the-given-users?num=500&type=11&list=21,310,5095,197518,88163)" (quoting [TheMaster](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/165717/themaster) [Oct 30 at 10:16](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5164/list-of-questions-nominated-for-reopening-because-lack-of-research-is-not-a-reas?cb=1#comment5846_5164))

Answer (score 1):

This question is not yet a great fit for the Stack Exchange format, in my opinion.  If I had privilege to vote to re-open, I would not vote to re-open it.

- The body of the post must explicitly articulate a question.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a question.  This post does not ask any question in the body of the post.  A question normally ends with a "?".
- We don't work like other sites, like Quora, where you put a one-liner question in the title and that's basically all you need; and you can optionally put some minor clarifications in the body.  That's how Quora works, but it's not how Stack Exchange works.  The format of that post might be a good fit for Quora, but it is not a good fit for Stack Exchange.
- People have already given extensive feedback on the question, but no one has has taken steps to address that feedback, at least not yet.  The [prior feedback](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4788/17465) includes "questions having the same body as the title aren't allowed", etc.  You were given a link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257762/160917 and ["Title-only" questions (i.e. questions without body) should be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66119/160917), which has more detail.  As that post said at the time, "This [has been] explained in so many different ways".  Everyone who is interested in that question has had an opportunity to edit the post to address this, but no one has taken the opportunity to do so.  The fact that the question was posted several years ago is not sufficient reason to re-open the question; to re-open a question, it must meet current-day standards.
- Re-opening can be done by the community.  It does not require diamond-moderator action or flags.  Diamond-moderators are not necessarily obligated to take action on flags requesting re-opening; they are free to leave it up to the community to vote as it chooses.

As the question is pretty old and already answered, there might be a range of opinions about the value of re-opening the question.  The only thing that re-opening a question does is allow someone to post a new answer.  The information available in the existing answer still remains even if the question stays closed.  Leaving the question in its current state does not cause the question to become deleted or invisible to search engines or other interested users.

In any case, if someone wants to post a new answer, I would suggest that they first spend a little time to edit the question based on Stack Exchange standards.

If you'd like the question to be considered for re-opening, I think the most constructive thing you could do is improve the question.  I suggest spending some time to improve the question to the maximum possible *before* debating what is the bare minimum for a question to be re-opened.  I encourage people to spend at least as much time revising these posts based on the feedback provided, as they spend on complaining about moderator actions.

Last, I'd like to offer my two cents on a broader point, in a somewhat philosophical vein.  I hope that not everything needs to be a battle of wills over principles and ideals.  From my perspective, part of being in a community is making compromises to the shared vision of the community.  I recognize that you have a particular view (you think the standard for questions should be lower), and I respect the basis for that view, but I also think what would most help the site and its mission would be to compromise and be prepared to bend at least a little, take feedback and act on it, and revise your questions based on community expectations.  I understand that you have a different opinion about what the minimum should be.  To me I perceive a pattern of "a running battle vs the moderators" over this issue.  I am not sure that this pattern is in the best interests of the health of this site.

Comment: Any suggestions on what OP should add to improve their question?

Comment: @galacticninja, I feel exhausted and discouraged to get such a question after I spent so much time typing this up. I'm sure you are a very capable person. My response already contains suggestions. I linked to other sources, too. One specific suggestion is to put the question in the body of the post, and make the title be a short summary.  Another suggestion is to read all the links and all of the feedback in the chatroom and use that to think about how to improve the question.  It's not my job to do that; I think that effort is best spent by whatever parties want to see the question re-opened.

Comment: I wonder how many times these suggestions and feedback have to be provided.  Act on them if you want, or don't act if you don't want.  It is up to you.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks. "One very specific suggestion is to put the question in the body of the post, and make the title be a short summary" I disagree with that: I prefer to have question titles that are as detailed as possible, so that readers know what the question is about. "Another suggestion is to read all the links and all of the feedback in the chatroom and use that to think about how to improve the question" I've done that and I don't see any concrete suggestion, except from the edits I've already made and showing research (and the latter is not compulsory). What other suggestions do you have?

Comment: FYI I addressed some of your feedback in an edit to the meta question. But really what I am looking for is concrete edit suggestion supported by site rules.

Comment: "Re-opening can be done by the community." On the contrary, I don't think it can. I've certainly not seen it happen in practice here, even with questions far more deserving than this one. There are just too few active 3k+ rep users. I think the [privileges should be lowered to "beta"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5185/197614) so the community does have the ability to close and reopen questions again.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the meta post from 3 years ago where you asked about that question. [The moderator who closed it said that you should have provided research details in the question body.](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/7584)

> The body of the question should include the question details and any research.

However, the community has recently discussed and agreed that we should not close questions based on the lack of research details from the OP, as clarified in the meta FAQ post “[Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)” The community managers also affirmed this policy.

So I agree with you that your question should be reopened according to our current site guidelines and community agreement.

I have flagged your question and referred to the research meta FAQ post and this meta discussion. I hope the moderators will either reopen your question or give a clear reason why they keep it closed.

To my knowledge, the burden of proof is on the close voters to justify their decision with relevant site policies and community consensus, not on the users who want to see the question reopened.

---

(The moderator who closed your question also mentioned that they closed your question because it had “the same body and title” and that the “question body should make it clear that the question is about using or directly interacting with the web app.” I noticed that you’ve already edited your question to address these issues, which leaves us with the “requires research” close reason I discussed above.)

Answer (score 1):

The community consensus is clear, showing no research is not a reason to close a question. I have reopened a large number of questions that don't show research and will continue to do so.

I reviewed this question mod-flagged for reopening and declined.  My decision was without consideration to the inclusion of research.

While a question mirroring a title may or may not reflect the effort invested, it at least makes the question self-contained, and forcing a user to add words unnecessarily doesn't serve to improve it.

> How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?

The problem with this question about the Slack web app is that it doesn't include details about the specific problem the OP is experiencing.

For example it doesn't provide an example of the search that isn't working.  It also doesn't describe what is being returned instead of the expected result.

This question lacks enough detail to properly identify the problem.  Without it, a search question like this can be dismissed as one that can be answered simply by opening the application itself.

The only way to interpret it right now is that you haven't reviewed the most basic information about using Slack and are using this site as a help desk.  I assume that is not the case and you have an actual problem and providing the details would go a long way to making this question a good fit for the site.

[image: Search box and filters in Slack]

[image: Search box at top of Slack]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Point taken, I understand now that you kept the question closed because it's too basic. After using Slack for over 6 years now, I agree that now it does seem quite basic. But as a new user in 2018, I wasn't aware of the `from:me` search keyword, and given the amount of views (25k) and upvotes (33 on the question and 39 on the answer), other Slack users are also looking for that information.

Comment: You don't need to know keywords you just need to want to find something. The UI will supply the syntax.  If it is about knowing the syntax then using the widgets and copying the resulting syntax provides that. I am not applying an "experienced user" test to the question, but a "has tried to do a search" test.

Comment: Got it, that's a fair point, I am not sure why I missed that in 2018. I believe in my mind, I needed to find a way to list all my messages because I was looking for one of my messages but I didn't know what keywords to search for, so I had to manually go through my messages, and I didn't realize that the search function would give me that list.  (Not arguing, just explaining)