# Why was the question "How can I prevent Outlook from automatically placing some emails in the junk folder?" closed as "details or clarity"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

1 mod closed [How can I prevent the Microsoft Outlook web interface from automatically placing some emails in the junk folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115108/18147) as "details or clarity". No comments were left. What's unclear or which detail needs to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should add a question to the question portion.

I see that it's been reopened already but please do that moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and reopening. I found [Should questions be asked in the body if they are included in the title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297116/178179) on Meta, which seems to agree with you, but in the past some users have edited the question out the body of some of my questions (I forgot on which SE site(s)).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, if you see someone do that, rolling back those edits is likely to be the best response.  The title should be a short summary of the post, not the question or the first sentence of the post.  The full question should be in the body of the post.