# List of questions nominated for reopening because lack of research is not a reason to close a question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, vote-to-reopen

Following [Cerbrus](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/148626/cerbrus)' [suggestion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5163/18147), here is the list of questions that were closed for lack of research. We'd like to ask the mods to reopen these questions given that it was clarified that [lack of research is not a reason to close a question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5142/18147).

Note that the list is incomplete, anyone is welcome to edit this meta question or post an answer to nominate other questions for reopening.

FYI [How can I view the list of the questions that were the most recently reopened on a given SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396024/178179). On WebApps, the link for users with 10k+ rep to view recently reopened questions is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days

| Question | Status | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Always mark as "Looks safe"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154103/always-mark-as-looks-safe#comment157764_154103) | Reopened on 2024-01-12 |  |
| [Any way to contact a user on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29197/any-way-to-contact-a-user-on-github#comment157634_29197) | Reopened on 2023-11-24 |  |
| [Can I format the Google Docs Table of Contents to only include certain headers?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102639/can-i-format-the-google-docs-table-of-contents-to-only-include-certain-headers#comment157631_102639) | Reopened on 2023-12-19 |  |
| [Can I permanently hide the YouTube chat window?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122414/can-i-permanently-hide-the-youtube-chat-window#comment157643_122414) | Reopened on 2023-11-14 |  |
| [Can only hosts invite their friends to a Facebook event?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49686/18147) | Reopened on 2023-11-22 |  |
| [Can people see if I read their messages on LinkedIn?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89944/can-people-see-if-i-read-their-messages-on-linkedin#comment157629_89944) | Reopened on 2023-12-19 |  |
| [Change a Facebook 'page owner' (not admin)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75299/change-a-facebook-page-owner-not-admin#comment157623_75299) | Reopened on 2024-01-11 |  |
| [Create a table of contents with hyperlinks in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/create-a-table-of-contents-with-hyperlinks-in-google-docs#comment157630_16429) |  |  |
| [Facebook account disabled?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/facebook-account-disabled#comment157650_8394) |  |  |
| [Hot keys to switch between tabs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40042/hot-keys-to-switch-between-tabs#comment157648_40042) | Reopened on 2023-11-21 |  |
| [How can I appear as an "anonymous animal" on Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/how-can-i-appear-as-an-anonymous-animal-on-google-drive#comment157628_51525) | Reopened on 2023-11-26 |  |
| [How can I bypass the annoying Quora login popup?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/110080/how-can-i-bypass-the-annoying-quora-login-popup#comment157644_110080) | Left closed | It's a duplicate. |
| [How can I change the default styles for Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6412/how-can-i-change-the-default-styles-for-google-docs#comment157636_6412) | Reopened on 2023-12-19 |  |
| [How can I export a Microsoft Office 365 Word online document to PDF without comments?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166158/18147) | Left closed | "This question doesn't show the most basic level of effort to understand the issue." |
| [How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166848/18147) | Reopened on 2024-01-11 ([relevant meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4882/7584)) |  |
| [How can I disable the authorization needed to open Google Sheets Macros?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/127052/18147) | Flagged by Franck, flag declined: [meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/18147) |  |
| [How can I import my papers to my ResearchGate profile from Google Scholar or ORCID?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170226/18147) | Flagged by Franck, flag declined: [meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5220/18147) |  |
| [How can I see Facebook notifications older than one week?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53784/how-can-i-see-facebook-notifications-older-than-one-week#comment157632_53784) | Kept closed | "Questions on application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications" |
| [How do I set a default Google Maps location?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57909/18147) | Reopened on 2023-12-08 |  |
| [How can I share my shopping cart with someone else on Amazon?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59685/how-can-i-share-my-shopping-cart-with-someone-else-on-amazon#comment157633_59685) | Reopened on 2023-11-11 |  |
| [How can I transfer ownership of a business page from my Facebook account to another?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75310/how-can-i-transfer-ownership-of-a-business-page-from-my-facebook-account-to-anot#comment157624_75310) | Reopened on 2023-11-15 |  |
| [How can I turn off unwanted labels without losing street names in satellite view?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118988/how-can-i-turn-off-unwanted-labels-without-losing-street-names-in-satellite-view#comment157639_118988) | Reopened on 2023-12-18 |  |
| [How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/how-can-i-view-all-the-messages-i-posted-in-a-slack-channel#comment157641_117076) | Kept closed | [Meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5191/18147) |
| [How do you block emails in Gmail with unknown domains?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/170107/how-do-you-block-emails-in-gmail-with-unknown-domains#comment157651_170107) | Reopened on 2023-12-10 |  |
| [How can I disable commenting on my Facebook post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26525/how-to-disable-comments-for-my-post-in-facebook#comment157627_26525) | Reopened on 2023-11-10 |  |
| [How to forward Facebook Messenger message to SMS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121831/18147) |  |  |
| [How to view total video view count of a YouTube playlist/channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89717/how-to-view-total-video-view-count-of-a-youtube-playlist-channel) | Kept closed | Closed as spam |
| [How to remove table borders in a google docs table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135242/how-to-remove-table-borders-in-a-google-docs-table#comment157638_135242) | Kept closed | "this particular question doesn't reflect the most basic level of effort to understand the issue." |
| [List all sheet names](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134812/list-all-sheet-names#comment157646_134812) | Reopened on 2023-11-09 |  |
| [Search for seller in Aliexpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123436/search-for-seller-in-aliexpress#comment157642_123436) | Reopened on 2023-12-19 |  |
| [Unable to see Add WhatsApp account in my Facebook business manager](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120603/unable-to-see-add-whatsapp-account-in-my-facebook-business-manager#comment157640_120603) |  |  |
| [What does the time next to the cell phone icon mean?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40496/what-does-the-time-next-to-the-cell-phone-icon-mean#comment157635_40496) |  |  |
| [Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github#comment157637_103374) | Reopened on 2023-11-06 |  |
| [Why does Facebook show last login of some friends and doesn't show that in others?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78371/why-does-facebook-show-last-login-of-some-friends-and-doesnt-show-that-in-other#comment157625_78371) | Reopened on 2024-01-12 |  |
| [Can I add audio to recorder.google.com?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4966/7584) | Question deleted; Flagged 2023-11-22 by galacticninja; Declined 2023-12-07 | "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" |
| [How can I disable "small caps" in my text in PowerPoint 365 on the web?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171637/7584) | Question deleted; [relevant 2023-08-12 meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5088/7584); Undeleted and reopened on 2024-01-12 |  |
| [How can I configure MTurk to send OTP codes by email instead of SMS?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142975/18147) | Reopened on 2024-01-11 |  |
| [How can I prevent the Microsoft Outlook web interface from automatically placing emails in the junk folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115108/18147) | Reopened on 2024-01-08 ([Meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4820/18147)) |  |

Comment: Why not make it general rather than just "lack of research", where community consensus is clear.

Comment: @TheMaster there are already normal review queues for re-open votes. I don't think this list should be mixed up with questions that don't fall under the ["Require research" discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5142/18147). That makes it a lot harder to review these, as you'd have to switch context for every single question.

Comment: The normal review queues don't work. Unless the community expressly orchestrates the timing of review queues, it's impossible to get a question reopened. I thought SO reopen queue was bad, but apparently here, [only 1 question got reopened in all of 2023 without moderator help](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1794029/post-closed-reopened-without-the-given-users?num=500&type=11&list=21,310,5095,197518,88163). Maybe something like this can be done for general reopen queue too?

Comment: Then that's a lack of user interaction. That's a different issue for a different Meta discussion. Let's not pollute __this__ cleanup effort with other unrelated closures.

Comment: I'm open to joining a reopen members club - especially for Google workspace, if anyone else is interested.

Comment: @Rubén "I think that the first reopen vote doesn't require too much reputation as someone with the edit privilege has a check box to send the question to the review reopen queue. The other two two votes require access to the reopen review queue": that's incorrect, we still need 3 reopen votes from +3k rep users according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394388/178179

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an effort to circumvent the normal site processes for nominating, and reviewing questions for possible reopening.  Further, it makes a fundamental claim that all the questions were closed for a lack of research which is never substantiated.

Comment: @Blindspots - Given the incredibly large number of questions being closed and the incredibly small number of questions being reopened, I think it's fair to say that the *"normal site processes for nominating, and reviewing questions for possible reopening"* is fundamentally broken here.

Comment: @Valorum I don't agree with your premise or your conclusion.

Comment: @Blindspots - Perhaps you could enlighten us as to whether *the proportion of questions that get reopened* is similar to other sites of this size? Spoiler, nowhere even close.

Comment: @Valorum your comments are off topic  for the question that was closed. Perhaps you would like to continue this discussion in chat or post a meta  question about it.

Comment: @Valorum I agree that Web Apps SE’s “*normal site processes for nominating and reviewing questions for possible reopening*” are fundamentally broken. That's why this meta post is well-received: [Reduce the reputation threshold to be allowed to cast a reopen vote on a closed question](//webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5180). It has many upvotes and positive feedback. The moderators should add a [status-review] tag to it so that the community managers can look into implementing it in Web Apps SE. This way, the community can have more say in deciding which questions should be closed or reopened.

Comment: @galacticninja When writing "Pending flag" that'd be good to add who raised the flag (so that we can ping them for updates if needs be).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I agree. That's a good idea. I'll try to edit the post later to mark the flags I've raised.