# Who wants to join the "question reopen club"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Unfortunately, there are very few active regular users with +3k rep, which is the minimum threshold for a regular user to cast reopen votes. As a result, questions are almost never reopened by the community, i.e. by regular users only:

> [only 1 question got reopened in all of 2023 without moderator help](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1794029/post-closed-reopened-without-the-given-users?num=500&type=11&list=21,310,5095,197518,88163).  [TheMaster](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/165717/themaster) [Oct 30 at 10:16](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5164/list-of-questions-nominated-for-reopening-because-lack-of-research-is-not-a-reas?cb=1#comment5846_5164)

Therefore, if mods are unwilling to reopen some questions, regular users need to coordinate, especially since reopen votes expire rather quickly.

So far myself and [TheMaster](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/165717/themaster) have shown some interest to help cast reopen votes on questions that we believe qualify for reopening ([examples](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5164/18147)).

Who else wants to join that "question reopen club"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is problematic to organize a question reopen club, or a question close club. The suggestion that the linked closed post has a list of questions closed for a lack of research is problematic, as is the suggestion that mods are blocking attempts to reopen questions closed for lack of research.

Comment: @BlindSpots Why is it problematic? Stack Overflow literally does exactly this ([SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)) and it hasn't caused any problems.

Comment: That "literally" is something different, for a different reason, to solve a different problem.