# Could mods please undelete and reopen all these questions that were automatically deleted due to incorrect mod closures ("Qs not showing research")?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, deleted-questions

Closed questions are automatically deleted in ~9 days if they have received no answers and have a score of 0 or less. There are a few more [details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) about this deletion rule, but that's a good approximation.

Over 100 questions were reopened after mods agreed to [stop](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147) closing questions that didn't show research. Over 95% of these questions were reopened after regulars users requested it, typically via flags at first, then via reopen votes after the rep threshold was lowered to [500](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5180/18147).

However, regulars users cannot see deleted questions, with a few exceptions (regulars users can see their own and 10krep users can see any deleted questions if have a link to it).  Therefore, regulars users can't request to reopen all these questions that were automatically deleted due to incorrect mod closures. The number of such questions are likely much higher than the number of questions  that the community was able to reopen recently.

Could mods please undelete and reopen all these questions that were automatically deleted due to incorrect mod closures ("questions not showing research")?

Since mods are the ones who closed questions, it should be much faster for them anyway to see which questions were closed due to not showing research, instead of putting that cleaning burden onto the community. (Many questions were closed by one mod without any comment or with a vague comment, which makes it tough for regular users to quickly guess why the question was closed.)

Comment: I agree. Since most, if not all, of the questions closed for [lack of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) were closed by the mods (causing Roomba to delete some of them), the mods should be the ones initiating the effort to reopen and undelete these questions. Tracking the posts that were closed for lack of research and subsequently deleted by Roomba would be a simpler task for the moderators due to moderator privileges and tools, and especially considering they were the ones who initially closed them.

Comment: "Since mods are the ones who closed questions, it should be much faster for them anyway to see which questions were closed due to not showing research". There's no good way to find questions automatically deleted that were closed with a specific reason. The best tool mods may have here is likely the ability to see all the close votes cast by a specific user (not sure how many legit votes are there though). Maybe SEDE has something more to offer, but that's accessible to everyone.

Comment: @Laurel Many questions were closed by one mod without any comment or with a vague comment, which makes it tough for regular users to quickly guess why the question was closed. This is why it's faster for the mod who closed the questions.

Comment: Questions are still being closed for lack of research(under needs details or clarity). Therefore, your request most likely would be ignored.

Comment: I'll look into this.  Give me a few days to review and circle back.

Comment: @Blindspots did you get a chance to look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I support this request. The community has clearly confirmed the consensus that [**we should not close questions for lack of research**](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584). All questions that were closed for this reason were closed by a moderator, leading to the automatic deletion of some of them by Roomba. The moderator who closed these questions should be the one initiating the effort to undelete and reopen them, in accordance with the community consensus.

The community (non-mods) has done most of the work to reopen the questions that were closed for lack of research, thanks to the [lowered reputation threshold for reopen votes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5180/7584). I think it will be a good gesture if the moderator who closed these questions is the one who reopens them; this would signify the moderator's acceptance of the community consensus and will rebuild trust between the community and the moderator team. I see several users working to reopen these questions, but they get no assistance from the moderator who closed them in the first place.

I have flagged some of the deleted posts indirectly by flagging their respective meta posts (listed at the meta post “[List of questions nominated for reopening because lack of research is not a reason to close a question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5164/7584)”), and one of them was reopened. However, I can’t see the other deleted posts, nor do they have associated meta posts that I know of, so I can’t flag them.

It would be much easier for the moderator who closed these questions to track them down and undelete them since they have the moderator tools and privileges to see deleted posts. They could also review their close vote history and/or their close reason comment history, for example.