# Why is this question on importing one's papers to one's ResearchGate profile from Google Scholar or ORCID kept closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, vote-to-reopen

Since a CM recently stated that [showing research is not required](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147), I flagged the question  [How can I import my papers to my ResearchGate profile from Google Scholar or ORCID?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170226/18147) for reopening, but the flag was declined ([no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx3UV.png) reason was given). Why is the question kept closed?

---

To answer [D.W.](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17465/d-w)'s comment, this a request for information about "why": it is not a request to re-open the question (since I want to understand the "why" first). I'd prefer if the mod explained their decision but I am also interested in hearing from other users about whether the question should be re-opened.

Comment: Is this a request for information about "why", or is it a request to re-open the question?  If it is a request for information, is it really a request for why the mod made that decision (which only the mod can answer), or are you perhaps seeking a discussion from the community about whether the question should be re-opened or not?  Please [edit] your post to be explicit and clear about exactly what you are requesting.

Comment: @D.W. thanks, added in the question.

Answer (score 5):

I have voted to reopen the question. There is a clear policy on research standards that was established by community consensus at [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5142/7584) I believe this question complies with the site policy and should be reopened. Quoting the relevant parts of the aforementioned meta post here:

> As demonstrated by the community, including research in a question is not required for question asking on Web Apps.
>
> While it can certainly be helpful to include your research in a question, it's not strictly necessary for a good question to be asked. A lack of present research does not cause a question to be unsatisfactory.

> Considering the above, close votes for lack of research won’t be necessary.

> However, closed questions can be reopened should they otherwise be of an adequate standard for Web Apps. If the only reason for a question's closure was due to a lack of research, it would qualify to be reopened.