# Why is this question on disabling the authorization needed to open Google Sheets Macros kept closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

Since a CM recently stated that [showing research is not required](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/18147), I flagged the question [How can I disable the authorization needed to open Google Sheets Macros?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/127052/18147) for reopening, but the flag was declined ([no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx3UV.png) reason was given). Why is the question kept closed?

Answer (score 3):

##### Update: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)(Question reopened) on Jan 25 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a moderator so I can't answer why a mod declined the flag, but I can give my opinion on the question.

To my mind the question is not in a good shape to collect further answers.  To my eyes it is not entirely clear what it is asking.  It's not clear which question it is trying to ask ("any way to stop...?" or "give permissions to everyone").  It's not clear to me what is meant by "give permissions to everyone I want to at some sort of permissions page" - the question would need to be edited to explain more clearly what it is asking.  We require that questions be clear to readers, and that it be clear what are the criteria that should be used to evaluate candidate answers, so that it is possible for voters to evaluate answers objectively.

Also, in this specific instance, I can't see any point in re-opening the question, as it appears it has already been answered.  People can still view that page.  The only thing closure prohibits is providing more answers.

If you have an actual problem you are facing right now, then I suggest posting a new question, and please make sure to explain the problem, make it clear what you are asking, [show your research](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and [be aware of the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  (As [our help pages say](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  If you aren't facing an actual problem, then I would suggest you leave it be and move on.)

I am aware of the history and I know you object to the practice of how some questions have been closed, and I suspect I can understand where that's coming from and can sympathize to some extent.  But I don't think this particular question is a good one to fight over.  I suggest focusing on what will be useful to the site's mission, more so than trying to enforce consistency with some preferred policy.  One way to be useful to ask good new questions, and another is to edit existing questions to improve them.

Comment: "I can't see any point in re-opening the question, as it appears it has already been answered." that's not a valid reason to keep a question closed.  "It's not clear which question it is trying to ask ("any way to stop...?" or "give permissions to everyone")." OP wants to disable the "authorization needed" to open Google Sheets Macros. They think one way could be "give permissions to everyone". So the question is clear to me, and I assume, to the mod who answered it.

Comment: " I suggest focusing on what will be useful to the site's mission, more so than trying to enforce consistency with some preferred policy. One way to be useful to ask good new questions, and another is to edit existing questions to improve them." Hence this meta question, which aims to understand how to write good questions (difficult to do when mods close questions without telling the exact reason, beyond some vague "Add details and clarify the problem being solved.").

Comment: If it is clear to you what is being asked, a great way to be constructive is to edit the question to clarify so that everyone can understand; or ask a new question that is clear.

Comment: More broadly, you asked "why?" and I gave you my opinion.  You don't have to agree with my opinion.  I recognize different people will have different views and different preferences and values, and that is fine.  I find it unpleasant to answer a "why?" question in good faith and then find someone trying to debate the issue with me when my answer does not agree with their preference.  If what you actually want is to request that action be taken, I think it would be better to ask that directly, rather than requesting information about "why".

Comment: I appreciate that you gave your opinion (e.g., I didn't downvote). I was just trying to understand the unclarity you perceive. Blindspots greatly improved the wordings of the question then reopened it, so we're all set now.