# Why was the question “How can I download the form field data for several forms at once in Adobe Sign?” closed by 1 mod as “details or clarity”?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

1 mod closed  the question [How can I download the form field data for several forms at once in Adobe Sign?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/160196/18147) as "details or clarity". No comments were left.

What's unclear or which detail needs to be added?

---

Since the question got  removed automatically, here's a copy of it:

> How can I download the form field data for several forms at once in Adobe Sign?
>
> [image]