# What part of the question "How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?" needs details or clarity?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, moderators

This Sept. 2022 question was closed unilaterally by a mod on 2023-01-26 as “needs details or clarity”: **[How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166848/7584)** — no comments were left to explain what details or clarity were needed.

The question was initially closed by a single moderator, but after I posted this meta post, it was then reopened by *three users, including Sathyajith Bhat, who was a moderator at the time*). ([Question timeline page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/166848/timeline)) However, the question was *closed again* on 2023-03-24 by the same moderator who closed it the first time, after they had posted an answer (which indicates that the question was not unclear), dismissing the actions of three users, including a moderator. The question has been closed twice without explanation, which is unfair to the OP and to the community.

I am puzzled by this situation — the reason for closing the question in the first place and why it was closed a second time despite having the support of two users and a moderator.

Link to question timeline: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/166848/timeline

The question essentially asks: “How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?” It is a straightforward and clear question that seeks to learn how to schedule comments on Reddit, a web app (which is on-topic). *Could someone please kindly clarify what part of it is unclear and point me to the community consensus that led to the closure of the question?*

> Rubén: The OP mentions Gmail, Twiter and "multiple source outlets" without providing enough details to be certain to what they are referring. Also it's not clear if they are looking for a built-in feature or if they are looking for a third party, API / scripting tools.

The part about “multiple source outlets” that OP mentioned is not essential for answering “How can I schedule a Reddit comment?” The question is clear and reasonable even without that part.

The possible solution (whether built-in, third-party, APIs, scripting tools, etc.) does not affect the clarity of the question. Any of those options would be a valid answer to the question. (That’s why OP asked in the first place; they don’t know the solution).

---

##### Oct. 2023 community consensus on whether research is mandatory

As of 2023-10-20, the community has reached a consensus on required research standards, which is documented in the meta post, [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) I believe the question in question follows the site policy and deserves to be reopened.

---

RE: 2023-11-06 comment by Blindspots ♦

> Please clarify what you mean by "how Gmail and Twitter do it" and provide additional details about the information you are referring to from "multiple sources"

In response to this moderator comment, I [suggested an edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158353) with multiple sources to clarify "how Gmail and Twitter do it" and how to schedule Reddit posts for later, which was approved on 2023-12-20. I believe this question is now clear enough and contains the required details to be answerable, if it previously did not.

---

RE: 2023-12-20 comment by Rubén - Volunteer Moderator - ♦

> This question has an accepted answer since February. The update done 17 hours ago doesn't make sense. You should post a new question instead.

Two users, including Blindspots ♦ (moderator), [have given their approval for the suggested edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158353), indicating that they find it coherent and supportive of the original poster’s intent. What else is missing or unclear in the question? I’m hesitant to create a new post, only to face closure for the same reasons as the current question. Please clarify what else needs details or clarity from the question, so that I can incorporate the feedback when I post a new question.

---

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what is still unclear about the question, as it seems straightforward and clear to me. Otherwise, I would like to request to please reopen the question again: **[How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/166848/how-do-i-schedule-a-comment-on-reddit)**

Comment: The OP mentions Gmail, Twiter and "multiple source outlets" without providing enough details to be certain to what they are referring. Also it's not clear if they are looking for a built-in feature or if they are looking for a third party, API / scripting tools.

Comment: So broad question with so few details nowadays doesn't look to be a good bit for this site. Consider to ask for a software recommendation on [softwarerecs.se] or ask on [meta.se] for a site recommendation to ask a question like that.

Comment: @Rubén The question is a *problem*-based question, *not* a software recommendation question. Related: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/7584)

Comment: Please guide the OP to improve their question or post yourselft a good question following the guideance from the link.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion started by a community manager about whether we should mandate research on questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584).

Comment: This question has an accepted answer since February. The update done 17 hours ago doesn't make sense. You should post a new question instead.

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator- "*The update done 17 hours ago doesn't make sense.*" It’s worth noting that two users, including Blindspots ♦ (moderator), [have given their approval for the suggested edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158353), indicating that they find it coherent and supportive of the original poster’s intent. Do you think there’s anything else missing or unclear in the question? I’m hesitant to create a new post, only to face closure for the same reasons as the current question."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which part of it is unclear?

Nothing is unclear to me, it is crystal-clear, and I therefore voted to reopen.

> The potential answer or solution (whether built-in, third-party, APIs, scripting tools, etc.) is also unrelated to the clarity of the question. Any of those potential solutions is a valid answer to the question. (This is why the OP asked in the first place; they don't know the solution)

The possibility to answer a question with a non-built-in solution shouldn't be a reason to close the question. Many (the majority maybe) questions on this site could be answered  with a non-built-in solution, and aren't closed (rightfully so).

Answer (score 4):

The moderator who closed the question twice apparently did so because they felt the question lacked research effort (moderators, please let me know if I’m mistaken). Quoting the [moderator's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4885/7584) to this post:

> Lets take this oportunity to review the guidance on how to ask and about what to do when a post is closed.
>
> [How to ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has four sections
>
> 1. Search, and research
>
> […]
>
> - **Research** refers to the efforts done by the OP to help themselves. As almost all web apps having a large user base Reddit has [help center](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us) and a [user help community](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/). Ideally the OP research efforts should include a deep review of these resources. It's also expected that user have *googled* to trying to content around the web. I this specific case, scheduling the publish of a post is a very popular topic, there are huge ammount of content about that and offers.

This subjective research requirement, which has resulted in the closure of dozens of questions, has been a source of frustration for several members of the community, myself among them.

I have reached out to the community managers about this question (and several others) that were closed for this reason. The community managers responded by creating the meta FAQ post “[**Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?**](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)". The community vote on that post indicates that the community agrees that *showing research is not a mandatory criterion for asking questions on Web Apps SE*, and therefore *moderators should not close questions for failing to meet any research standards*.

Based on this community consensus and site policy, I believe the question is valid and deserves to be reopened. I have flagged it with a custom reason requesting for it to be reopened and citing the meta FAQ post, “[Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)”, but my flag was declined: “a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it”.

I hope to clarify this issue further with the mods.

Comment: And the other 3 points raised in that answer? You really need to stop singling out the "needs research" point, unless you can ___prove___ that that's the _sole_ reason these questions got closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus The other 3 points are *not* reasons to close the question. "1. Be on topic" Reddit is an on-topic web app. "2. Be specific" Looks specific to me. The user who closed should clarify what's not specific in the question. "3. Make it relevant to others." This is relevant to others. In fact, I would like to know the answer to the question myself. Also, the burden of proof is *not* on me, the close voter is the one who should **prove** that their closure is in line with site policy and *community consensus*. As you can see the close voter's answer to this meta post has a negative score…

Comment: … suggesting that the community disapproves of their action.

Comment: Those 3 points are just you disagreeing with the other 3 reasons. They don't _prove_ that research is the sole reason the mod closed it. The downvotes on that answer also don't validate your focus on the "research" reason. You claim he _"did so because they felt the question lacked research effort"_. You can not substantiate that claim. How many times does that need to be pointed out? I feel like this effort of re-opening potentially valid questions is being muddied by your (and another user's) constant focus on ___only___ the "lacking research" aspect.

Comment: I'm not saying these questions _should_ stay closed, just that you guys _constantly_ go about it the wrong way.

Comment: @Cerbrus The community moderator is the one who should explain the site policy (community consensus) behind closing the question, so it’s not up to me to justify anything. As you can see, I reached out to the moderators about this matter nine months ago, but I still haven’t received a clear and specific answer. That’s why I added “moderators, please let me know if I’m mistaken” in my post. If the community disagrees with the reason for the question's closure, then perhaps the question deserves to be reopened. If I’m going about this the wrong way, I’m open to hearing other ideas.

Comment: As I already said, it's your _constant_ focus on _only_ that "research" closure reason. One that I have yet to see substantiated, despite often asking people for something, _anything_ that proves that _that_ is the (sole) reason many questions are closed. Again, I want to make this cleanup / reopen effort work, but y'all need to understand that focussing ___only___ on the "research" reason isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: @Cerbrus Once the moderators clarify exactly why they closed the question, I will revise my post accordingly. It's unclear to me why the question was closed in the first place, as I've already stated in my question. When I reached out to the CMs about it, they posted the “research” meta post in response (which shows they talked to the moderators, who said they closed questions for lack of research). That’s why I brought up “research”. The moderator’s answer here doesn’t address my question at all—it’s "guidance" on what to do when a question is closed, which is not what I asked about.

Comment: _"It's unclear to me why the question was closed in the first place"_ yet you make the blatant accusation: _"did so because they felt the question lacked research effort"_. That's not productive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149540/discussion-between-galacticninja-and-cerbrus).

Answer (score -4):

Lets take this oportunity to review the guidance on how to ask and about what to do when a post is closed.

[How to ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has four sections

1. Search, and research
2. Be on topic
3. Be specific
4. Make it relevant to others.

- **Search** refers especifically to search for content from Web Applications. In the specific case of [reddit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit) there are only 49 visible questions so its understanble that [the question in focus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/166848/7584) does not include links to previous questions. Ideally  people should include links to the most relevant related posts.
- **Research** refers to the efforts done by the OP to help themselves. As almost all web apps having a large user base Reddit has [help center](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us) and a [user help community](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/). Ideally the OP research efforts should include a deep review of these resources. It's also expected that user have *googled* to trying to content around the web. I this specific case, scheduling the publish of a post is a very popular topic, there are huge ammount of content about that and offers.
- **Be on topic** the question should be focused on using Reddit, it might be related to using it together with web browser features including extensions, userscripts and together with other web apps. Using with installable software might be OK while it limits to the setup like getting settings from the Reddit user account page. Straight request for software recommendations are off-topic. Questions about using an API that are not directly related to using an online IDE to create a user defined function / automation or that require professional grade advice are off-topic.
- **Be especific** refers to provide enough details and context. Lack of details might cause having a lot of back and forth, people seeing the questions as a [brainstorming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming), "shoping list" or discussion in a tipical online forum that motivated the SE model. The OP mentioned three different three things without providing any details. There are a lot of ways to scheduling  emails in Gmail and tweets in Twitter, multiple of them work aren't limited to these tools.
- It should clear how the solution asked is relevant to others, in this case Reddit users.

**About the closing**

It's perfectly fine that you have opened this question in Meta. Regarding the **reopening**, *the OP should participe* to solve the post problems  / clarify what is being asked by providing additional details. If the OP don't comeback in a reasonable time you might ask about the same later. In the meantime you and others community members might help this OP by fixing small problems and providing guidance to the OP through comments or in a chat room.

Refences

- [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: If a question is bad, it merits a downvote. The bar for closing a question should be higher, especially if the community has already made it clear that the question should be reopened.

Comment: “*Research refers to the efforts done by the OP … Ideally the OP research efforts should include …*” As per community consensus and site policy established at [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584) — we should not close questions because the OP did not include their research on their question. I’ve flagged the question citing our site policy, but my flag has been declined: “a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it”. Can you please reopen the question in line with our site policy? I’d appreciate it.