# Another task for the task jar: Close questions about defuncted web applications

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, clean-up, vote-to-close

According to [The Web Application Graveyard](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3797/88163), created in 2015 by [ale](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale),

> questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

then

> Such questions should be Closed with the community-specific reason. Use Other - add a comment

So my "plan" is when a question appears on the Homepage or on the Related questions, look if the question includes one of the tags of the known defuncted web applications.

I put plan between quotes because there is no due date or specific time assigned to work on this. Consider this as a piece of paper in a task jar.

If someone is interested in joining, please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since July 19, 2023, **Album Archive**, https://get.google.com/albumarchive, a service to access albums from retired products like Google Hangouts and Picasa Web Albums, was retired.

This and recent questions about Google Photos related to [picasa-web-albums](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picasa-web-albums) make me remember the old "graveyard" post. Some posts having [google-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-photos) and [picasa-web-albums](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picasa-web-albums) should not be closed if the question focus is on using Google Photos rather than on Picasa Web Albums. If the focus is on the other direction, the question should be closed.